# events on HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I trigger a button in HTML using the javascript?

I tried to use the `<script></script>` the HTML file and it works perfectly fine, but then I want to use a javascript file to trigger when clicking a button in HTML.

here is the code: 
JAVASCRIPT in HTML `<head></head>` tag:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js">
<script src="jsFiles/index.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
             <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Message</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" id="a_id">Log Out</a>
              </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT FILE:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#a_id").click(function(){

            swal({title:'Logout', 
            text:'Do you want to logout this Account?', 
            icon:'warning', 
            buttons: true, 
            dangerMode: true
            })
            .then((willOUT) => {
                if (willOUT) {
                    window.location.href = 'page-logout.php', {
                    icon: 'success',
            }
            }
            });

            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: You don't appear to have included jQuery, yet are using jQuery methods.

Comment: @AniketG no sir. There is no error either. nothing happens when i click the button.

Comment: @ObsidianAge What do you mean sir?? Can you help me working with it?

Comment: Is this `<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>` inside of the index.js?

Comment: @AlexAbulencia put `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your html right above your `<script src="jsFiles/index.js"></script>` and try it then. jQuery wouldn't work if you don't include it, which is what Obsidian Age is saying

Comment: @AniketG . Ok sir. I'll try it.

Comment: @Ele Yes. It's inside the js file

Comment: @AlexAbulencia usually when stuff like this doesn't work, the first thing you should do (the first step in deubgging) is to put `console.log("works");` inside the `.click` function, and comment out everything else. This will show you wether the error is in your code **inside** your function, or if the error is the **function itself**.

Comment: @AniketG Thanks sir! without the link you'd give me, i am not going to figure out the missing. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexAbulencia is your problem solved?

Comment: @AniketG Yes SIr! and also i implemented the answer below and it works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove everything is not javascript code, so your file `index.js` should look as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#a_id").click(function() {

    swal({
        title: 'Logout',
        text: 'Do you want to logout this Account?',
        icon: 'warning',
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true
      })
      .then((willOUT) => {
        if (willOUT) {
          window.location.href = 'page-logout.php', {
            icon: 'success',
          }
        }
      });

  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir! You and @Aniket G helped me a lot. Thanks